How to globally change the column padding in v-data-table of vuetify in nuxt3?
Environment: Nuxt3 + Vue3 + Vuetify3.
When using Vuetify3, I found that the padding of column used in v-data-table is too much. So I want to shrink it to padding: 0 2px. After googleing and reading https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/sass-variables/. I found there are two approachs.
solution 1:
modify every page which uses v-data-table with below code:
    <style scoped>
    .v-data-table :deep(td) {
      padding: 0 0px !important;
    }
    
    </style>

solution 2:
I prefer to this approach.
According to https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-table/#sass-table-column-padding. It says that the padding of column in v-data-table is controlled by $table-column-padding. Therefore, I made below changes:

check my packages.json and it already has a sass package.

        "dependencies": {
          "@mdi/font": "^7.2.96",
          "@nuxt-alt/proxy": "^2.5.8",
          "@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt": "^1.2.0",
          "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.5.1",
          "axios": "^1.6.8",
          "mdi": "^2.2.43",
          "mitt": "^3.0.1",
          "pinia": "^2.1.7",
          "pinia-plugin-persistedstate": "^3.2.1",
          "sass": "^1.63.6",
          "vue": "^3.3.13",
          "vue-router": "^4.2.5",
          "vue3-print-nb": "^0.1.4",
          "vuetify": "^3.4.8",
          "vuex": "^4.1.0"
        }


Add /assets/scss/settings.scss with:

        @use 'vuetify/settings' with (
          $table-column-padding: 0 2,
        );


Well, I don't know how to continue because the vuetify page said below:


But I can not find the file vite.config.js. Nor is there a folder named src/styles/
Below is my /plugins/vuetify
    import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
    import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
    import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
    import * as labsComponents from 'vuetify/labs/components'
    import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
    import {aliases, mdi} from "vuetify/iconsets/mdi";
    
    /**
     * https://pictogrammers.com/library/mdi/
     */
    export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
        const vuetify = createVuetify({
            ssr: false, // https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/
            // components,
    
            components: {
                ...components,
                ...labsComponents
            },
            directives,
    
            icons: {
                defaultSet: 'mdi',
                aliases,
                sets: {
                    mdi
                }
            }
        })
    
        nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
    })

Below is my nuxt.config.ts
    import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt/config'
    
    export default defineNuxtConfig({
      css: [
        '@/assets/css/main.css',
        'vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass',
        'mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css',
        '@/assets/scss/style.scss',
      ],
    
      build: {
        transpile: ['vuetify'],
      },
    
      vite: {
        define: {
          'process.env.DEBUG': false,
        },
      },
      components: {
        "dirs": [
          {
            "path": "~/components/tenant",
            "global": true
          },
            "~/components"
        ]
      },
      typescript: {
        strict: true,
        typeCheck: false
      },
 
      runtimeConfig: {
        // The private keys which are only available server-side
        apiSecret: '123',
        // Keys within public are also exposed client-side
        public: {
          // apiBase: '/api'
          apiBase: process.env.NUXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE
        }
      },
      modules:[
        '@pinia/nuxt',
        '@pinia-plugin-persistedstate/nuxt'
      ]
    })

Any instruction for how to complete the above approach 2 ?

The first solution is actually totally fine, you could have some global CSS rather than a local scoped one.
There are plenty of ways of achieving so in Nuxt3.
As for the Vite part, you use that bundler with Nuxt3.
You even have some edits on it ('process.env.DEBUG': false,), so you could put a vuetify object inside of vite, or create an external vite.config.js file if you want or even maybe add a vuetify object nested in your defineNuxtConfig, choice is yours.
Both solutions are pretty much equally good, either you use the regular CSS approach that is more universal or the Vuetify-specific one.
Some people maybe asked such Vite customization in their Github issues already.
